# Windows XP Taskbar Grouping

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

It would be really nice if I were able to group applications in the xp taskbar according to the project I was working on...

For instance if i had two folder windows open, an im window, and a word doc... it would be nice to be able to group those in the taskbar and then right click on the group to minimize all of them. Then when I was ready to come back to them i could right click on the group and choose restore and it would restore those windows from their minimized state...

Anyone ever hear of this functionality? Or should I use a multiple desktop tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you end up going to the multiple desktops route, I recommend [VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/). It's surprisingly light on system resources and you can move windows to different desktops and zoom around desktops with hotkeys (or use the tray menu for either). It doesn't offer any live view candy or anything like that, but it might just work for what you want.

Comment: I've kind of gone the multiple desktops route... I'm running VMWare... :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Taskbar Shuffle](http://nerdcave.webs.com/) allows you to reorder the taskbar's application buttons using drag-and-drop. So while it doesn't put them inside one button, it will let you group the buttons any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

[Taskbar Button Manager](http://www.innovative-sol.com/taskbar-button-manager/index.htm) is another taskbar manager that allows reordering even inside groups.

Answer (score 0):

To add one more tool to the list: for taskbar buttons reordering there's also [Taskix](http://taskix.robustit.com/) (which is described as running OK on 32-bit and 64-bit versions of: Windows XP, Server 2003, Vista, Server 2008).

Answer (score 0):

I was myself looking for an answer to similar requirements. I was able to find a useful utility, and it looks like very few people are aware of such a solution, going by so many questions and relatively little answers on this topic.

Try wsTaskborg Taskbar Organizer. It allows to group any arbitrary applications into logical groups in taskbar. No need to use multiple desktop tool.

http://download.cnet.com/wsTaskborg/3000-2072_4-10632012.html

http://w-shadow.com/wstaskborg/